# Why do we have separate complex-integration and contour-integration tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-management

It seems like these are nearly identical in nature. The tag for complex integration was created three months ago and the contour-integration tag has been around for over two years. I feel like the complex-integration tag should be a synonym for contour-integration.

Comment: Hmmm.  I am inclined to agree, as virtually all instances of [tag:contour-integration] indicate the complex plane.  But is this necessarily the case?  How about real line integrals over curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: There's a separate line-integrals tag floating around somewhere which would take care of that, I think. Line integral problems don't show up quite as much, so I think it's okay to distinguish contour integration from line integration. Also the wiki for contour-integration specifically has complex plane integration in mind for that matter.

Comment: when starting complex analysis, sometimes there are problems asking one to integrate complex functions that are not complex-differentiable over curves in $\mathbb{C}$. These are the only reason I might see for the complex-integration tag.

Comment: @robjohn: I think those cases would still fall under the umbrella of contour integration; the contour integral is defined without regard to differentiability, e.g. via Riemann-Stieltjes integration.  Even when concerned primarily with holomorphic functions, one uses contour integrals for functions not a priori known to be holomorphic, e.g. in applying Morera's theorem.

Comment: One could integrate over a subset of the plane that is not a contour. However, the description of [complex integration tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-integration) suggests it is to be used synonymously with contour integration. So I think the tags should be synonyms.

Comment: @Behaviour we could easily integrate a complex valued function without using a contour. For instance, take [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942061/simple-complex-line-integral-over-a-rectangle/992758), I would call this complex integration but it wouldn't fit in with contour integration.

Comment: @dustin Why would not it fit? There's a contour of integration right there, the boundary of the rectangle.

Comment: @Behaviour You are correct. I was thinking of something else. I was thinking of it as solely applying to residues.

Comment: Wait, do people actually distinguish between contour, line, and path integrals?  To me, they are synonymous and make sense for any nice manifold, not just the complex plane.

Comment: @SpamIAm I think they only distinguish contour integrals as they show up repeatedly in complex analysis although it's just a realization of a line integral. Just to distinguish the context easily.